# Can UPI OCP/OKD cluster be deployed with worker nodes on the masters?

Tags: openshift, cluster-computing, okd, redhat-containers

I have baremetal server with only 32GB, which are insufficient for creating an OCP or an OKD cluster. Is it possible to make a cluster with the compute nodes on the control plane nodes, instead of creating another VM's for them. I know the existence of CRC, but is not suitable for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 32GB what you are realistically looking for is "single node openshift". (Or the OKD equivalent.)

In OpenShift terminology a cluster where worker workloads run on the same nodes as the master workloads is usually called a "[compact cluster](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/delivering-a-three-node-architecture-for-edge-deployments)". Although this is the direct question you ask (and is a supported configuration), you'd be looking at 24 GB for each master node, so 72 GB total, which is more than you have.

So you'd be looking at a single node running both worker and master workloads, typically called [Single Node OpenShift](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/meet-single-node-openshift-our-smallest-openshift-footprint-edge-architectures) (or SNO).